# Debug Assertion Fails On Dynamic Array

Tags: c++

So here is my working code for a simple dynamic array. This has to be a sample code for a very entry level data structure implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AdvancedArray {
public:
    AdvancedArray();
    ~AdvancedArray();
    int get_size() const; // get the number of elements stored
    double& at(int idx) const; // access the element at idx
    void push_back(double d); // adds a new element
    void remove(int idx); // remove the element at idx 
    void clear(); // delete all the data stored
    void print() const;

private:
    double* elements;
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    AdvancedArray* arr = new AdvancedArray();
    cout << "The Array Size is: " << arr->get_size() << endl;
    cout << "Pusing Values: 1.2, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5 in the Array. " << endl;
    arr->push_back(1.2);
    arr->push_back(2.1);
    arr->push_back(3.3);
    arr->push_back(4.5);
    arr->print();
    cout << "The Array Size is: " << arr->get_size() << endl;
    cout << "The Element at Index 2 is: " << arr->at(2) << endl;
    cout << "Deleting Values: 2.1 from the Array. " << endl;
    arr->remove(1);
    cout << "The Array Size is: " << arr->get_size() << endl;
    arr->print();
    cout << "Clearing the Array: " << endl;
    arr->clear();
    cout << "The Array Size is: " << arr->get_size() << endl;
    arr->clear();
    return 0;
}

AdvancedArray::AdvancedArray()
{
    size = -1;
    elements = new double[100]; //Maximum Size of the Array
}

AdvancedArray::~AdvancedArray()
{
    delete[] elements;
}

int AdvancedArray::get_size() const
{   
    if(size < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return size;
}

double & AdvancedArray::at(int idx) const
{
    if (idx < 100 && idx >= 0 && size > 0) {
        return elements[idx];
    }   
    cout << "Index Out of Bounds." << endl; 
}

void AdvancedArray::push_back(double d)
{
    if (size >= 100)
    {
        cout << "Overflow Condition. No More Space!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        elements[++size] = d;
        cout << "Element Pushed In Stack Successfully!" << endl;
    }
}

void AdvancedArray::remove(int idx)
{
    if (size >= 100 || size < 0)
    {
        cout << "No Such Element Exists!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = idx; i <size; i++)
        {
            elements[idx] = elements[idx + 1];
        }
        size--;
        cout << "Element Deleted In Stack Successfully!" << endl;
    }
}

void AdvancedArray::clear()
{
    delete[] elements;
    size = -1;
}

void AdvancedArray::print() const
{
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        cout << elements[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

So every time I try to run this I have the 2 problems:

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Why is the heap getting corrupted (I searched about the error code and that's all has to say)? Is my code doing some major access violations?  I am using VS2015.

Comment: Think about what happens when you call `clear` twice.

Comment: ... or clear and calling the destructor.

Comment: @RetiredNinja removed one clear, still error persists!

Comment: If you delete memory block on clear, how user is supposed to use your dynamic array class after that?

Comment: You've a nice debugger in your hand, Press F10 and F11 and know the exact cause. Asking people with suggestions won't help much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do `delete [] elements` *three* times without setting `elements` to `nullptr` in between. That leads to *undefined behavior* the second time (and third) time.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir That's because you do it *three* times. Just updated my question. Don't remove the `clear` call, set `elements` to `nullptr` and you don't have to worry about it. Doing `delete[]` on a null pointer is allowed.

Comment: Better simply remove `delete []` from clear. You allocate only  in constructor. If user clears your array and attempts to add a value it will segfault too.

Answer (score 2):

When `size == 99`, the following piece of code attempts to access `elements[100]`:

```
if (size >= 100)
{
    cout << "Overflow Condition. No More Space!" << endl;
}
else
{
    elements[++size] = d;
    cout << "Element Pushed In Stack Successfully!" << endl;
}
```

You need to change `++size` to `size++`.

Comment: Still I get heap corruption detected :(